# Set all empty cells to zero except for certain columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file called "gar_nv", "nbrLines" is the number of lines ,defined in my code. I have given names to my columns. "listCol" is a function returning a list of these names.
I would like to set all empty cells to zero except the cells of the following columns: "GCFRRE", "GCDEP1", "GCDEP2", "GCDEP3", "GCTYC0", "GCTYC1", "GCTYC2", "GCTYC3","GCBAC0", "GCBAC1", "GCBAC2", "GCBAC3". Knowing I have thousands of rows, this code takes a long time to run. Is there a way to make it faster ?

```
Dim rng As Variant, i As Long

With gar_nv
    For i = 1 To nbrLines - 1
        For Each rng In ListCol
            Select Case rng
            Case "GCFRRE", "GCDEP1", "GCDEP2", "GCDEP3", _
            "GCTYC0", "GCTYC1", "GCTYC2", "GCTYC3", _
            "GCBAC0", "GCBAC1", "GCBAC2", "GCBAC3"
            
            Case Else
                If IsEmpty(.range(rng).Rows(i)) = True Then
                .range(rng).Rows(i).Value = "0"
                End If
            End Select
        Next rng
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: I would first loop through all the columns building a range (filtering out the columns you are showing here). Once your range is defined, use `my_range.Replace("",  0)` that should do it fairly fast. Another way, by looping like you do, should be inside an array and paste that array back to the sheet (it will be faster because everytime you interact with the sheet takes a toll on the execution time).

Comment: *I would like to set all empty cells to zero* Check [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) and [XlCellType enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcelltype). You can select all blank cells in a column and set them up to 0, no need of loop trough rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your columns are named ranges like headers in the image:

[image]

You can do:

```
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng As Range
Dim Listcol As Variant
Dim i As Long
Listcol = Array("A", "B", "C_", "D") 'list of all named ranges

For i = 0 To UBound(Listcol)
    Select Case Listcol(i)
        Case "B"
            'we do nothing
        Case Else
            'we replace blanks with 0
            Set rng = Range(Listcol(i)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=0" ' set them to 0
            rng.Value = rng.Value 'replace formula with value
            Set rng = Nothing
    End Select
Next i

Erase Listcol

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Notice named range `B` has been excluded:

[image]